# Home/Drawer button in Actionbar cannot be focused with keyboard/controller

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-actionbar-compat

I'm implementing some controller/keyboard navigation in my application for accessibility, and I can't seem to make my drawer button gain keyboard focus.

Setting up the actionBarDrawerToggle (in onCreate):

```
this.drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
this.drawerLayout.setScrimColor(0x99000000);
this.actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, this.drawerLayout, R.string.Root_Drawer, R.string.Root_Drawer);
this.actionBarDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_utilitybar_menu);
this.actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
this.drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(this.actionBarDrawerToggle);
```

Setting up the action bar (also in onCreate):

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(ACTIONBAR_BACKGROUND_COLOR)));
actionBar.setElevation(0);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

The other buttons on the action bar are focusable, but I can't go left (dpad left or keyboard left arrow) from the leftmost of those buttons onto the home button itself. For those buttons, I needed to mark them as focusable in order to get the keyboard to navigate to them, eg (from onCreateOptionsMenu):

```
MenuItem alertItem = menu.add(0, R.id.menu_alert, 0, null);
alertItem.setActionView(this.alertIconActionView);
alertItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
this.alertIconActionView.setFocusable(true);
this.alertIconActionView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

But there doesn't seem to be a view I can obtain for the home button that will allow me to set it to be focusable elements.